# Textbox value will be plotted to a graph

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm just trying to create a graph where the user can input data into textboxes and then plot the data in a chart using vb.net. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may use System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart()
You can generate the designer using the win forms then get the designer code and have it customized in your web app. Very flexible.

```
//Here is sample code :

public ActionResult CreatePieChart()
        {
            Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(450, 300);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImage);
            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            //Creating Chart Temaplate
            var PieChart = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            var PieChartArea = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            var Legend = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
            Legend.Docking = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Bottom;
            var ChartSeries = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            PieChart.Palette = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.None;
            var PieChartTitle = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title();
            PieChart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 10);
            PieChart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(450, 300);
            PieChartArea.Name = "PieChartArea";
            Legend.Name = "Legend";
            PieChart.Name = "PieChart";
            PieChart.Text = "PieChart";
            PieChart.ChartAreas.Add(PieChartArea);
            PieChart.Legends.Add(Legend);

            //Initializing Chart Components
            List<string> ChartXValues = new List<string>(); //X Values
            List<Single> ChartYValues = new List<Single>(); //Y Values

            ChartSeries.ChartArea = PieChartArea.Name;
            ChartSeries.Legend = Legend.Name;
            ChartSeries.Name = PieChart.Name;
            PieChart.Series.Add(ChartSeries);
            PieChartTitle.Name = "PieChart";
            PieChartTitle.Text = "PieChart";
            //Data Binding
            PieChart.Series[ChartSeries.Name].Points.DataBindXY(ChartXValues, ChartYValues);
            PieChart.Series[ChartSeries.Name].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
            PieChart.Series[ChartSeries.Name].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            PieChart.Series[ChartSeries.Name].Label = "#VALY{##0.0}%";
            PieChart.Series[ChartSeries.Name].LabelForeColor = Color.White;

            PieChart.SaveImage(imageStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            PieChart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.SystemDefault;
            Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            imageStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            graphics.Dispose();
            bitmapImage.Dispose();
        }

//To Display in page :

<img src="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") />
```